# How to install the latest development version of Python with conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm interested in trying the latest Python (3.6.0-rc1) in a virtual environment.  Is there a way to use `conda` for installing development releases?  The traditional way does not appear to work, e.g.:

`conda create -n rc python=3.6.0.rc1`

I realize these releases are new and may not be available yet on [Anaconda proper](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs), but perhaps there are channels for dev releases or an alternative method I do not know.

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the conda-forge channel

```
conda create --name rc python=3.6.0.rc1 --channel conda-forge --override-channels
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to verify this technique is non-destructive to my existing channels.  It seems `–override-channels` ensures conda only searches the specified channel, correct?  It doesn't mutate any configs?